# mssql server giving error for php connection

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

```
$serverName = "192.168.0.245\SASTO"; 
$sqlinformation = array("Database"=>"HCM8","UID"=>"","PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$sqlinformation);
```

Error:

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\t.php on line 30
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

this connection working for one server but other servers cannot connect using this connection. giving above error.

Comment: Please, show sqlsrv_query() call. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this server can access `192.168.0.245`? Also check that the user is allowed to connect from this servers IP.

Comment: You should also add some error handling for the connection. That will most likely give you some reasons for _why_ the connection fails. Check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) for info about that. Just remember that in production, you should log the error instead of printing it (and then handle the error properly instead of letting it break the code).

Comment: Yes this server is accessed by an other server through this connection it self. but i use same connection on my PC it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what that comment was suppose to answer. The fact that _another_ server can connect to that database doesn't mean that _the current_ server (which fails) have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to [sqlsrv_connect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-connect?view=sql-server-2017) returns `false` and I quess that you have call to `sqlsrv_query()` after that. Always check the result from `sqlsrv_connect()`.

In your case (if SQL Server is accessible), one possible reason for this error is that you try to connect with [SQL authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-sql-server-authentication?view=sql-server-2017), but you don't provide values for `UID` and `PWD` connection options. If you want to connect to server with [Windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-2017), just remove `UID` and `PWD` connection options.

```
<?php
# Connection
$serverName = "192.168.0.245\SASTO"; 
$sqlinformation = array(
    "Database"=>"HCM8",
    "UID"=>"",
    "PWD"=>""
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $sqlinformation);
if ($conn === false)
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Query
$sql = ' .. some statement ...';
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: @Hasee What does sqlsrv_connect() return?

Comment: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message]  this is the error.

Comment: @Hasee Your PHP Driver for SQL Server is not poperly installed. Install missing ODBC Driver and try again.

Comment: I have added this, extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Comment: @Hasee Then install ODBC driver. Versions 3.2 and 3.1 of the PHP driver for SQL Server require Microsoft ODBC Driver 11.